# ReactNative - FlatList not updated until scroll

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a problem with `FlatList` component which does not update until scrolled.

[image]

I tried add log to `renderItem` and `keyExtractor` both methods called with correct data but list didn't update.

Here is a render method:

```
render() {

    const messages = this.props.messages
    const message = this.props.message

    return (
        <View style={[styles.container]}>
            <FlatList
                ref={"flatList"}
                contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
                data={messages}
                renderItem={(listItem) => {
                    return <MessageBuble message={listItem.item}/>
                }}
                keyExtractor={(item: Message) => {
                    return item.id
                }}
            />

            <View style={[styles.textInputContainer]}>
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.textInput}
                    value={message}
                    multiline={true}
                    onChangeText={this.props.messageChanged}
                />
                <Button title={"Odeslat"} onPress={() => {
                    if (this.props.sendMessage) {
                        this.props.sendMessage(this.props.message)
                    }
                }}/>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Which navigator are you using? Try setting `removeClippedSubviews={false}`

Comment: I use StackNavigator from `react-navigation` library and removeClippedSubviews don't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add extraData in FlatList and retry

```
<FlatList
    extraData={this.props}
    ....
```

Comment: Great! Then you accept the answer :) . It works as FlatList does not re-render when there is change in state or props. But if we want to re render the FlatList then we need to pass a prop extraData to it. In case if it were dependent on state then you would have passed extraData={this.state}

Comment: Documentation says: `If any of your renderItem, Header, Footer, etc. functions depend on anything outside of the data prop` . but in my case `data` property change always.

Comment: The docs for FlatList say "This is a PureComponent which means that it will not re-render if props remain shallow- equal. Make sure that everything your renderItem function depends on is passed as a prop that is not === after updates, otherwise your UI may not update on changes. This includes the data prop and parent component state."

Comment: Also you can pass extraData={messages} only if your renderItem is not dependent on any other state or props. But in general this isn't the case as we make use of many things included in our state/props in our renderItem.

Comment: `extraData={messages}` or `extraData={this.props.messages}` don't work

Answer (score 0):

Tried the extraData, but that does not work.

There was an issue on Android where content was not visible when I returned back from another page to home screen (where the flatlist was present). The content was visible when I scrolled it a bit.

I assigned the main list to the extraData attribute, and could see that it changed in size via console logs. But the content remained invisible. Finally, used

```
onContentSizeChange={() => {
      if (list.length > 0) {
        ref.current.scrollToOffset({ animated: true, x: 0 });
      }
    }}
```

and it worked.