# FlatList rendering as blank even when the data(Array) is supplied to the component

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render out a list of object data using FlatList in my React Native component, however I am getting a blank screen without any errors on the console which is why it is rather difficult to get to the bottom of the issue here. The data is made available to the component using Redux-Saga approach and supplied to the FlatList which is showing up a blank screen without any errors. To double check if the FlatList is working fine I did a mockup array in component and passed to the FlatList which renders out the UI as expected. Following is the code I am using here;

=======================================================

```
    class Mobile extends Component {

      componentDidMount() {
        let { readPostsAction } = this.props;
        readPostsAction();
      }

      renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
          <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeDetails', { item })}>
              <Card>
                <CardItem header>
                  <Text style={styles.titleHeading}>{item.title}</Text>
                </CardItem>
                <CardItem cardBody>
                  <Content style={styles.cardContainer}>
                    <CustomCachedImage
              component={FitImage}
              source={{ uri: contentURL(item.attachments[0].url) }}
              style={{ width: width, height: 200 }}
                    />
                    <HTML tagsStyles={bodyText} html={reduceStringLength(contentText(item.excerpt))} />
                  </Content>
                </CardItem>
              </Card>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        )
      }

      keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;

      render() {
        const { dataSource } = this.props;
        console.log('this.props', this.props);
        return (
          <View>
            <FlatList
              data={dataSource}
              keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
            />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }

    function mapStateToProps({ launchAppReducer }) {
      return {
        isLoading: launchAppReducer.isLoading,
        dataSource: launchAppReducer.data
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps, { readPostsAction: actions.readPostsAction })(Mobile);
```

=======================================================

Here is the screenshot of the console [image: Screenshot] showing that the data is available in the component.

Comment: Strange, try to render the FlatList only when dataSource.length > 0 and also add extraData={this.props.isLoading} on your FlatList

Answer (score 0):

Modify your FlatList code and retry

```
<FlatList
    data={dataSource}
    extraData={this.props}
    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it didn't work by adding `extraData={this.props}`. It appears to me that the re-rendering of component is not happening when the data is made available via Redux-Saga props.

Comment: Apart from that, even if your component would have re-rendered then too you need to add extraData or else it won't work.

Comment: Thank you for the input, interesting fact is when I supply the mock array within the component it works as expected.

Comment: I think you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50204947/reactnative-flatlist-not-updated-until-scroll/50204993#50204993

Comment: Thanks for sending that, please have a look on these screenshots https://ibb.co/hAtU17 => (data is supplied using Redux Saga props). Another one https://ibb.co/d9hiTn => (when data is supplied locally from the component)

Answer (score 0):

There was the problem at in the Actions, I was firing `readPostsActions` instead I should have fired `readMobilePostsActions` - it works fine now, thank you guys all the all input and help here.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this style in your Flatlist:

```
<FlatList
   style={{height:'100%'}}
   data={dataSource}
   keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
 />
```